# iOS (Swift 4) - Catch error from third-party library function which does not throw

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-analytics-sdk, flurry-analytics

Are there any good ways to catch exceptions originating from function calls by third-party (closed source) libraries/frameworks when the function does not explicitly `throw`?

Curious how to properly handle this in both Obj-C and Swift.

Ex: Integrate closed source Analytics SDK into my app. That SDK is crashing during initialization. I don't want my app to crash, but I want the app to continue functioning without the Analytics SDK.

Comment: In Swift *no throw, no catch*

Comment: @vadian - I figured in Swift, a non-`throw`ing function could not be wrapped in a `catch`. However, I was wondering if the same is true in Obj-C. For example, what if I wrote a Obj-C class which caught the exception and called that from my Swift project? Does such a mechanism exist?

Comment: Unlike Swift in ObjC you can catch exceptions so I guess you can catch also exceptions caused by the Swift code but it's always a better idea to write reliable code to avoid any exception.

Comment: @vadian late to the party, but your comment should be an (accepted?) answer